# Twilio key press and hold

Tags: twilio

Does the Twilio API allow pressing and 'holding' of a dial key?

I'm writing an app that requires that dial key be held N seconds. Is this possible with Twilio?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, not.. it's really only a binary state of pushed/not-pushed or how many times it was pushed.

What's your goal here?

(Disclosure: Twilio evangelist here..)

Comment: Always good to know the Twilio team is keeping tabs here :).  I'm trying to interact with another automated system programmatically using the Twilio API and am worried about an instant keypress not being registered on their end. Think when you're calling some customer service number and dial 0 to get an agent. Would that work with the <Dial>0</Dial> syntax or would you have to hold it down?

Comment: We often lurk. :) You're close on the Dial portion, but you should actually use the sendDigits attribute. The docs are here: http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number#attributes-sendDigits It tells Twilio to play the tone through to the listener.